# ESP8266 connection with a locally hosted server

Tags: django, iot, esp8266

I have a Django server hosted locally. I ran my server using `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` so that it is accessible from any devices that are connected to my WiFi.

Any computers or smartphones in my network can simply go to my computer's IP Address `192.168.0.0:8000` via their browser to see my Django page.

I would like to use an ESP8266 module to send a GET request to the locally hosted Django page. The following AT Commands are used.

```
AT+CWMODE=1
AT+CWJAP="SSID","PASS"
AT+CIPMUX=1
AT+CIPSTART=0,"TCP","192.168.0.0",80  <--Problem arise here, hence I could not move on with my GET request
```

All but the last command was executed successfully. When I run the last AT Command to establish a TCP connection with my local server, I get an error.

```
ERROR
0,CLOSED
```

Currently, I'm still not super proficient with networks and backend. Any long explanation and/or answers will be well appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said that to load the Django page from a browser you go to 192.168.0.0:8000

Change

```
AT+CIPSTART=0,"TCP","192.168.0.0",80
```

to

```
AT+CIPSTART=0,"TCP","192.168.0.0",8000
```

That will load the page from port 8000 (like your do from a browser) instead of port 80 (the default web server port).

Comment: I changed the port on my server side instead of changing the esp's at command and it worked! For some reason, accessing port 8000 from the at command throws up the same error.